# How can I check that a filter applied to a listobject column with vba is legal?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, named-ranges

Filtering a listobject(excel table) with a value that doesn't exit results 
all rows instead of none

can I get no rows? 
can I get list of optional legal parameters?

example
listobject with col A

A
1
4
5

filter a=2 results 1,4,5
filter a=1 results 1
in this example I would like :
opt 1: get no results for filtering with 2
opt 2: get a list of legal params: 1,4,5

Comment: I think this question would be more suited for stackoverflow?

Comment: How are you filtering? This is tagged vba, are you writing a macro? What's the macro look like?